# Google Oauth2.0 web application's "Authorized redirect URIs" must end with a public top-level domain (such as .com or .org)?

Tags: django, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-python-client

When create a Google API Oauth2.0 Credentials on [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com), I choose "Web Application" Application type.

In the "Authorized redirect URIs" field, I can use http://127.0.0.1/callback, it work fine for me on local development.

but when I want to use Google API Oauth2.0 Credentials on my server(let's say 99.99.99.99), I have to use http://99.99.99.99/callback as my "Authorized redirect URIs", but google give me a warning:

> Invalid Redirect: http://99.99.99.99/callback must end with a public
>   top-level domain (such as .com or .org)

Except to bind a public top-level domain to my server, what else can I do?

I develop in Django and use [oauth2client](https://github.com/google/oauth2client) to deal with Google API Oauth2 , So there are two table "oauth2_authentication_credential", "oauth2_authentication_flowmodel" in my database which have the credential value in it, I copy them from my localhost to sever, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you can use fake domain for example: yourrealdomain-localhost.com. Add this domain to windows hosts file and make it looking for 127.0.0.1 So, you can enter this domain in Google dev console.

Comment: @ vee your method look good.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is help text near "Authorized redirect URIs" field, that clearly states that you cannot use public IP addresses:

> Authorized redirect URIs
>
> For use with requests from a web server. This
>   is the path in your application that users are redirected to after
>   they have authenticated with Google. The path will be appended with
>   the authorization code for access. Must have a protocol. Cannot
>   contain URL fragments or relative paths. **Cannot be a public IP
>   address.**

`127.0.0.1` is not public IP, but a [loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback), that's why http://127.0.0.1/callback works fine. [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) also could be used: http://localhost/callback

> Except to bind a public top-level domain to my server, what else can I do?

You can use free DNS by http://xip.io/. So for IP `99.99.99.99` use http://99.99.99.99.xip.io/callback. And it would be resolved to http://99.99.99.99/callback.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of  loopback and public IP. I try to visit http://99.99.99.99.xip.io (replayed 99.99.99.99 with my real server ip), then it return a page with the text "Welcome to nginx on Fedora!", this is not server page, is there something wrong?

Comment: All that xip.io is doing is resolving hostnames (`99.99.99.99.xip.io` in that case) to IP addresses specified in that hostname and nothing more. 
"Welcome to nginx on Fedora!" is a nginx default landing page. Have you deployed your application to a server and configured it? Do you see your app at http://99.99.99.99? If your application is accessible at http://99.99.99.99, then http://99.99.99.99.xip.io should work fine.

Comment: I use CentOS 7 and Nginx on my server. I can access my Django project at 99.99.99.99. According to You suggest, I found that the page with "Welcome to nginx on Fedora!" is my Ngnix's 404 page. But I get different page when I visit 99.99.99.99 and 99.99.99.99.xip.io , Maybe there is some misconfig on my Nginx config file?

Comment: My guess is that in nginx config in server block for your app you have something like this: `server_name 99.99.99.99;`. If so, then change it to `server_name 99.99.99.99 99.99.99.99.xip.io;`.

Comment: your guess is right. After I change server_name to 99.99.99.99 99.99.99.99.xip.io in ngnix.conf, 99.99.99.99.xip.io work just like 99.99.99.99. Thanks man, I have accept your answer for this question.

Comment: There are reserved top level domains ( https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606 ). So, Google should allowed these domain for local environment testing. This can make things a lot easier. How to let Google know?

Comment: @vee - It's been a while, but I just opened this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/254199033