# Invalid Redirect: domain must be added to the authorized domains list despite it being there

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, oauth, subdomain, google-developers-console

I am attempting to connect to the Google Analytics API using Matillion ETL on an AWS EC2 instance in an effort to load a data lake.
When I try to add the callback URL into the Google Developer Console http://ec2-99-99-99-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com/oauth_redirect.html, I get the error:

```
"Invalid Redirect: domain must be added to the authorized domains list before submitting."
```

I do have amazonaws.com added to the Authorized Domains on the OAuth Consent screen. If I add, compute-1.amazonaws.com/oauth_redirect.html, it accepts it. So I know it's recognizing amazonaws.com, but not for my specific EC2 instance

I was thinking it was because it's a sub-sub-domain, but I'm not sure if that matters. Based on other posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109708/google-oauth2-0-web-applications-authorized-redirect-uris-must-end-with-a-pub) other people have been able to connect.

I've also tried adding a new record set in Route 53 instead of the AWS provided URL, but I don't know how to change the default callback URL in Matillion. I've sent their support team a separate question about that, and will let you know if that resolves it.

I do think this is a problem on the Google side that should resolve it though. Could there be some setting in the Google console that I'm missing to allow this?

Edit: Using the Route 53 URL instead when signing into Matillion will force the OAuth config to use that instead when getting the callback URL. I'm able to connect to Google Analytics now. I will leave this post up in case anyone else runs into the subdomain.subdomain.domain.com issue with Google

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36112649:

> You can use free DNS by http://xip.io/. So for IP 99.99.99.99 use
>   http://99.99.99.99.xip.io/callback. And it would be resolved to
>   http://99.99.99.99/callback.

Further, make sure the redirect URI in the `.env` file or other similar configuration in AWS is set to `http://99.99.99.99.xip.io/callback`.